# Tensorflow ValueError: No variables to save from

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have written a tensorflow CNN and it is already trained. I wish to restore it to run it on a few samples but unfortunately its spitting out:

> ValueError: No variables to save

My eval code can be found here:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

import main
import Process
import Input

eval_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/model.ckpt-30"
checkpoint_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/checkpoint"

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

def evaluate():
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    sess.run(init_op)

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)

    saver.restore(sess, eval_dir)

    images, labels = Process.eval_inputs(eval_data = eval_data)

    forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)

    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(forward_propgation_results, labels, 1)

    print(top_k_op)

def main(argv=None):
    evaluate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `tf.train.Saver` must be created *after* the variables that you want to restore (or save). Additionally it must be created in the same graph as those variables.

Assuming that `Process.forward_propagation(…)` also creates the variables in your model, adding the saver creation after this line should work:

```
forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)
```

In addition, you must pass the new `tf.Graph` that you created to the `tf.Session` constructor so you'll need to move the creation of `sess` inside that `with` block as well.

The resulting function will be something like:

```py
def evaluate():
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    images, labels = Process.eval_inputs(eval_data = eval_data)
    forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(forward_propgation_results, labels, 1)

  with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver.restore(sess, eval_dir)
    print(sess.run(top_k_op))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, although I did remove the eval data = eval data and it should still work. Right now when I run the program, python doesn't output anything.

Comment: I'm not sure where `eval_data` comes from, since that name isn't bound in your example. Does `Process.eval_inputs()` use an input pipeline? Perhaps you need to add `tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess) after running `saver.restore()`.

Comment: Thank you. The code is fixed but a new error has popped up after adding that line.     E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] targets[0] is out of range

Comment: "The tf.train.Saver must be created after the variables that you want to restore (or save). " What is the reason for this ?

Comment: what is `eval_data` and Why we must create variables before restore?

Answer (score 3):

Simply, there should be at least one tf.variable that is defined before you create your saver object.

You can get the above code running by adding the following line of code before the saver object definition.

The code that you need to add has come between the two ###.

```
import tensorflow as tf

import main
import Process
import Input

eval_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/model.ckpt-30"
checkpoint_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/checkpoint"

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

### Here Comes the fake variable that makes defining a saver object possible.
_ = tf.Variable(initial_value='fake_variable')

###
saver = tf.train.Saver()
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that since TF 0.11 — a long time ago yet after the currently accepted answer — `tf.train.Saver` gained a [`defer_build` argument in its constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#__init__) that allows you to define variables *after* it has been constructed. However you now need to call its `build` member function when all variables have been added, typically just before `finilize`ing your graph.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(defer_build=True)
# build you graph here
saver.build()
graph.finalize()
# now entering training loop
```