# Tensorflow: Why must `saver = tf.train.Saver()` be declared after variables are declared?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Important clarification: I was only running this section, the graph definition, in a notebook enviroment. I had not run an actual session yet.

When running this code:

```
with graph.as_default(): #took out " , tf.device('/cpu:0')"

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  valid_examples = np.array(random.sample(range(1, valid_window), valid_size)) #put inside graph to get new words each time

  train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, cbow_window*2 ])
  train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
  valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)
  valid_datasetSM = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

  embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', 
    initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))

  softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights',
    initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                         stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))

  softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', 
    initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]),  trainable=False )

  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

  embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*cbow_window*2, embedding_size] )


  segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(cbow_window*2)

  averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

    #return tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               #labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keepdims=True))
  normSM = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(softmax_weights), 1, keepdims=True))

  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  normalized_embeddingsSM = softmax_weights / normSM

  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
  valid_embeddingsSM = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    normalized_embeddingsSM, valid_datasetSM)

  similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings))
  similaritySM = tf.matmul(valid_embeddingsSM, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddingsSM))
```

I got this error

ValueError: No variables to save

while pointing to this line

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

I searched stack overflow and found this answer

[Tensorflow ValueError: No variables to save from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626435/tensorflow-valueerror-no-variables-to-save-from/38627631)

So I simply put that line at the bottom of the graph definition like so

```
with graph.as_default(): #took out " , tf.device('/cpu:0')"

  valid_examples = np.array(random.sample(range(1, valid_window), valid_size)) #put inside graph to get new words each time

  train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, cbow_window*2 ])
  train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
  valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)
  valid_datasetSM = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

  embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'embeddings', 
    initializer= tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
  softmax_weights = tf.get_variable( 'softmax_weights',
    initializer= tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                         stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))

  softmax_biases = tf.get_variable('softmax_biases', 
    initializer= tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]),  trainable=False )

  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is
  embed_reshaped = tf.reshape( embed, [batch_size*cbow_window*2, embedding_size] )

  segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(cbow_window*2)

  averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean(embed_reshaped, segments, name=None)

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keepdims=True))
  normSM = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(softmax_weights), 1, keepdims=True))

  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  normalized_embeddingsSM = softmax_weights / normSM

  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
  valid_embeddingsSM = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    normalized_embeddingsSM, valid_datasetSM)

  similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings))
  similaritySM = tf.matmul(valid_embeddingsSM, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddingsSM))

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

And then there were no errors!

Why is this so? The graph definition is only defining the graph, not running anything. Perhaps it's an bug prevention measure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not have to. `tf.train.Saver` has a `defer_build` argument that, if set to `True`, allows you to define variables after it has been constructed. You then need to call `build` explicitly though.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(defer_build=True)
# construct your graph, create variables...
...
saver.build()
graph.finalize()
# go on with training
```

Comment: I guess this changes my view on how a graph is set up and run. I thought any tensorflow variables declared are just definitions until the graph is run in a session. Is the tf.train.Saver() and exception to this?

Comment: @Santosh, that is still true. All the variables are just defined, until you initialise them. Initialisation is generally the first step you do before running the graph in a session.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation on tf.train.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) the `__init__` method has a parameter `var_list` with the description:

```
var_list: A list of Variable/SaveableObject, or a dictionary mapping names 
to SaveableObjects. If None, defaults to the list of all saveable objects.
```

This suggests that the saver makes a list of variables to save when it's first created, which by default contains all of the variables it can find. If no variables have been made, an error makes sense since there are no variables to save.

Random examples:

```
import tensorflow as tf
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

The above throws an error, and so does below

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

But this last example runs,

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.Variable(0.0)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this changes my view on how a graph is set up and run. I thought any tensorflow variables declared are just definitions until the graph is run in a session. Is the `tf.train.Saver()` and exception to this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't really know. You could ask a new question about it :p